# Verify Faraday's law of induction

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields

I need to design a procedure for an experiment to verify Faraday's law of induction. I'm given:

1. A Helmholtz coil of radius 15 cm
2. Three plastic spheres of radii 1 cm, 1.5 cm, and 2 cm.
3. A spool of copper wire
4. A digital multimeter
5. A plastic cylinder 5 cm tall and with a radius of 2 cm.
6. Typical clips (banana clips, etc.)

We can use the Helmholtz coil to produce a uniform magnetic field. Then if we wrapped the plastic spheres/cylinder a certain amount of times and suspended them inside of the magnetic field that we created, would we be able to use the multimeter to calculate the magnetic flux? If so would this then verify Faraday's law of induction? Or am i totally on the wrong track

Thanks in advance for any help, I wanna stress the fact that I don't want to just be given the answer if possible. Just a step in the right direction. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Does the Helmholtz coil have a power supply? If it does, is it DC or AC?

Comment: Does a Helmholtz coil need a power supply to create a uniform magnetic field? Because in the equipment provided there is not a power supply listed.

Comment: Maybe the Helmholtz coil has a built-in power supply? Otherwise I don't know how it can create magnetic field.

Comment: That must be the case. Let's say it's DC :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wind the wire around the cylinder and measure the voltage in the resulting "new" coil as you move it in the field of the Helmholtz coil (say, along the axis - the field is fairly constant in the center, but varies off the center). However, to verify the Faraday law, you also need to measure time. To this end, you may suspend one of the spheres on a wire and use it as a pendulum, whose period can be calculated if you know the length of the wire and $g$. The length of the wire can be measured, as we have several objects with known dimensions.